# Trying to get focus on all buttons in a QButtonGroup

Tags: c++, qt, events, event-handling, keyboard-events

I am trying to get focus on all the QPushButtons in QButtonGroup. I am installing eventFilter on all buttons added in the button group and capturing the Tab key press event on each button and shifting the focus to next button.
I am able to achieve that, but the problem is while shifting the focus backwards using Shift + Tab. I am unable to capture the Shift + Tab event in the eventFilter. Only shift modifier press works fine

Here is the code:

```
bool Widget::eventFilter( QObject * inObject, QEvent * inEvent )
{
    if( inEvent->type() == QEvent::KeyPress )
    {
      QKeyEvent * keyEvent = static_cast< QKeyEvent * >( inEvent );
      if( keyEvent )
      {
         if( keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab && keyEvent->modifiers().testFlag( Qt::ShiftModifier ) )
         {
           //move focus backwards;
            return true;
         }
         return false;
      }
    }
}
```

Please Help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Qt::Key_Backtab to achieve the shift+tab.
No need to explicitly catch 2 modifiers.
It is ready made in Qt